# Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'text' to data type int

Tags: sql

```
         select *
           from aBook as ab left join 
                org as org on ab.idorg = org.id left join 
                class as ar on ab.idclass = ar.name
          where dateofstatus <='2020/01/17' and dateofstatus >= '2019/12/31' 
       order by orgname;
```

I need to catch name column from table class, my connection between tables aBook and class is the same id column.

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using.  (2) Provide sample data and desired results.  (3) Provide information about the types of the columns in the tables.

Answer (score 1):

It is entirely unclear what the problem might be.  However, this `JOIN` condition is quite suspicious:

```
on ab.idclass = ar.name
```

Normally, a name is a string.  And an `id` is a number.  If the naming conventions matches the expected types, then this would cause the error referred to in the title.